# Why can't I create a subdomain with www in CloudFront?

Tags: subdomain, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53, cname

Can you please help me figure out why I cannot create a subdomain with www?

I have domain.com. I have a certificate for said domain that includes: `www.domain.com`, `domain.com`, and `*.domain.com`.

I want to create `www.subdomain.domain.com` records through AWS CloudFront.

I can create `subdomain.domain.com` no problem. I just cannot create the `www` version. I get an error that states `The certificate that is attached to your distribution doesn't cover the alternate domain name (CNAME) that you're trying to add.`

That should be covered by `*.domain.com`, no?

Attempts to create the CNAME record in Route53 manually have also been no help. I don't get the CNAME error, but I still get 403 errors on `www.subdomain.domain.com`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `www.subdomain.domain.com` is indeed not covered by your certificate. The `*.domain.com` wildcard covers domains like: `subdomain1.domain.com`, `subdomain2.domain.com`, etc; it doesn't cover `www.subdomain.domain.com` because the `*` wildcard works only for a single subdomain (first subdomain after the dot). For this to work, your certificate would need to cover `*.subdomain.domain.com`.